# Qual a melhor maneira de organizar um diretorio para um projeto web?

Tags: php, html, composer, bower

Qual a melhor maneira de organizar os diretorios para um projeto PHP de desenvolvimento web?

Answer (score 0):

Podes escolher uma framework e normalmente ao criares um projecto ela fará esse trabalho por ti, mas um bom "boilerplate" seria:

```
app/
   styles/
   scripts/
   views/
        home.html
        etc...
   assets/
       fonts/
       imagens/
 config/
```

Comment: Não existe uma resposta correta para a sua pergunta, pois é baseada em opiniões, as pessoas fazem da maneira que lhes parecer mais conveniente.

Comment: Tem toda a razão, eu só estava a dar uma ideia para quem nunca se teve de organizar... Esta estrutura muda de pessoa para pessoa e de framework para framework..não há maneira correcta.

Comment: eu digo isso porque por exemplo se quero organizar meu projeto para distribuicao do fonte, desenvolvimento e tambem de produção. qual seria o melhor metodo?

Comment: eu usaria uma pasta client/ com tudo o que precisasse, e depois compilava e minificava tudo para uma pasta build/, que so teria um main.css, main.js, e o resto que fosse preciso, tudo pre-processado e minificado.